# Can't run AppImage on desktop by doubleclicking or clicking "Open"

Tags: 20.04, appimage, doubleclick

New linux user, currently running on Ubuntu 20.04.

Double-clicking an AppImage file on desktop or using "right click > Open" does nothing and doesn't display any errors either, however double-clicking it from the file manager or running it from terminal works. Any ideas why?

Comment: You Should Be Able To Run The AppImage File..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Solution 1 :

Right Click On The Appimage File And Go In Properties.

[image]

Then Go In Permissions.

[image]

Tick Allow Executing File As Program, and Both access : read and write, It must look the same as the image.

[image]

> Solution 2 :

**Open terminal, copy and paste the following command :**

```
sudo chmod +x name.appimage
```

**Leave A Like, Or Comment.**

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same issue and yes, making the file executable is necessary, however, to be able to open the **appimage** from desktop you will have to:

1. Right click on your desktop
2. Click on **Settings**
3. Scroll down to the bottom and look for **Action to do when launching a program from the desktop**
4. Click the drop down menu on the right of it and set it to **Launch the file**

Now launching the **appimage** from the desktop by clicking on it should work. At least this did it for me.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone in the future comes across this, you should know that **Ubuntu 22.04 does not have [FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace)](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libfuse2) library installed** by default. That is probably the case if you select **Minimal Installation** instead of full installation. You're gonna have to install libfuse2 manually:

> sudo apt install libfuse2

combine this with the accepted answer and you're good to go.

Comment: I have several Ubuntu 22.04 desktops and they all have Fuse by default.

Comment: @David mine did not come with it and I had to manually install it. I chose "minimal installation" at the beginning. Maybe that's it? It's not just me either, for instance: https://itsfoss.com/cant-run-appimage-ubuntu

Comment: You should edit your question to add that you did a min install and not a standard one.

Comment: In Debian, I accidentally removed libfuse2 via "apt autoremove". Adding that pkg back in per Amir ZM's solution fixed the issue. BTW: Be wary of "apt autoremove". I've had that command hose Debian systems on more than one occasion...

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here.

I had tried the answers on this thread, but they weren't enough.

My problem was that I had downloaded the **32-bit version** of balenaEtcher AppImage app. Alas, 32-bit apps are no longer supported in current Ubuntu versions.

You must be sure to download **the 64-bit version of the AppImage app**! Ubuntu doesn't alert you that it is a 32-bit version. It simply doesn't run it.

Answer (score 0):

Appimages will not launch from the Thunar file manager. If you're on Ubuntu 22.04, like I, go back to using Files file manager.